# convert INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS COLUMN_DEFAULT to underlying datatype

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a smalldatetime column in one of my tables with a default value of January 1st 2012.

Later I want to check that the actual default value has been set to the correct value. However when I read back the value from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS sql has added formatting. The following code demonstrates my problem

```
DECLARE
  @Requireddefaultdate smalldatetime = 'Jan 1 2012',
  @Actualdefaultdate smalldatetime,
  @Actualdatestring nvarchar (128) ;

CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable 
       (thedate smalldatetime CONSTRAINT df_mytable_thedate DEFAULT 
        CAST('Jan 1 2012' AS smalldatetime)
 ) ;

INSERT INTO mytable DEFAULT VALUES;

SET @Actualdatestring = (SELECT column_default
                       FROM information_schema.columns
                       WHERE table_name = 'mytable') ;

PRINT @Actualdatestring; --result: (CONVERT([smalldatetime],'Jan 1 2012',0))

--Now I would like to convert @actualdatestring to smalldatetime  
--so I can compare it to @requireddefaultdate

SET @Actualdefaultdate = @Actualdatestring; -- gives error 'Conversion failed 
-- when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.'

SET @Actualdefaultdate = CAST((@Actualdatestring)AS smalldatetime); 
--gives same error as above

--Added below - this is the script I used for dynamic sql
declare @dynsql nvarchar(500), @paramdef nvarchar(500);
--  SET @dynsql = N'Set @param_actdate = CAST(@param_defaultstr AS smalldatetime)';
--Above line changed as below in response to comment/answers. 
--Now get single error: Incorrect syntax near '=' but seems to be closer to a correct solution.
SET @dynsql = ' ''Set '' + @param_actdate + '' = (Select  '' +  @param_defaultstr + '' )'' ';

SET @paramdef = N'@param_actdate = @Actualdefaultdate output, 
@param_defaultstr = @Actualdatestring';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @dynsql, @paramdef, 
@param_actdate = @Actualdefaultdate output, @param_defaultstr = @Actualdatestring;

--finally drop the table
DROP TABLE dbo.mytable;
```

I have also tried doing the conversion using sp_executesql with parameters with no success (script for this added above).

I could do string manipulation to extract just the date part of @actualdatestring but I feel there must be a more elegant method and I'm missing something obvious

Thanks for your help

Comment: `sp_executesql` ought to work, what problems did you have? You will need to escape the single quotes in the string literal by doubling them up. Why are you checking this anyway?

Comment: Thanks. I have taken on board your comment and Triple's answer - especially about escaping the single quotes and edited my script above. It isn't working yet but I think it is much closer. The reason for this is that my database tables are created automatically from a set of tables forming the database requirements. This algorithm to check the default value is part of my unit testing suite. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually I might have sent you off on the wrong direction there. `DECLARE @DynSQL nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT @Result = ' + @Actualdatestring;DECLARE @Result smalldatetime;EXEC sp_executesql @DynSQL,N'@Result smalldatetime OUTPUT',@Result OUTPUT;SELECT @Result`

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE 
  @Requireddefaultdate smalldatetime = 'Jan 1 2012', 
  @Actualdefaultdate smalldatetime, 
  @Actualdatestring nvarchar (128) ; 

CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable  
       (thedate smalldatetime CONSTRAINT df_mytable_thedate DEFAULT  
        CAST('Jan 1 2012' AS smalldatetime) 
 ) ; 

INSERT INTO mytable DEFAULT VALUES; 

SET @Actualdatestring = (SELECT column_default 
                   FROM information_schema.columns 
                   WHERE table_name = 'mytable') ; 

PRINT @Actualdatestring; --result: (CONVERT([smalldatetime],'Jan 1 2012',0)) 
exec('select ' + @actualdatestring)
DROP TABLE dbo.mytable;
```

A little nasty cause it uses dynamic SQL, but that could work for you.

Comment: Thanks to yourself and Martin. I have changed my script slightly in light of these comments and although I still haven't got it working I think it is closer to a correct solution. Using select seems to be the the key to removing the formatting. I haven't used your exec method because I need to 'grab' the output from the select so I can compare it to the specified value. This was my reasoning for using sp_executesql. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't quite got the answer yet but this is my much improved (and shorter)script. Now all I have to do is work out why when I copy the string contents from the results pane it works OK but when I use the string itself then it doesn't. I will post my final answer when I get there. Thanks again for the help.

```
DECLARE 
  @Requireddefaultdate smalldatetime = 'Jan 1 2012', 
  @Actualdefaultdate datetime, 
  @Actualdatestring nvarchar (128),
  @dynql nvarchar(500), @paramdef nvarchar(500) ; 

CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable  
   (thedate smalldatetime CONSTRAINT df_mytable_thedate DEFAULT  
    CAST('Jan 1 2012' AS smalldatetime) 
 ) ; 
 INSERT INTO mytable DEFAULT VALUES; 

SET @Actualdatestring = (SELECT column_default 
                   FROM information_schema.columns 
                   WHERE table_name = 'mytable') ; 
--replace single quotes with double quotes for inclusion in dynamic sql string
SET @Actualdatestring = REPLACE (@Actualdatestring, '''', '''''') ;
print @Actualdatestring; --prints (CONVERT([smalldatetime],''Jan 1 2012'',0))
--copy the contents of @Actualdatestring from the results pane into the dynamic sql string
SET @dynsql  = 'Set @param =  (select (CONVERT([smalldatetime],''Jan 1 2012'',0)))'; -- works OK
--SET @dynsql  = 'Set @param =  (select @Actualdatestring)'; -- doesnt work,get conversion error
set @paramdef = N'@param smalldatetime output, @param2 nvarchar(128)'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @dynsql, @paramdef, @param = @Actualdefaultdate output, @param2 = @Actualdatestring;

if(@Actualdefaultdate <> @Requireddefaultdate)
begin
  print 'Error';
end
else
begin
  print 'OK'
end

--finally drop the table 
DROP TABLE dbo.mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got something to work. I concluded that sql was happy with the contents of the string but when I used the string variable itself then sql declared a coversion error. So my approach has been to embed the string contents prior to calling sp_executesql.

```
DECLARE 
  @Requireddefaultdate smalldatetime = 'Jan 1 2012', 
  @Actualdefaultdate datetime, 
  @Actualdatestring nvarchar (128),
  @dynsql nvarchar(500), @paramdef nvarchar(500) ; 

CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable  
   (thedate smalldatetime CONSTRAINT df_mytable_thedate DEFAULT  
    CAST('Jan 1 2012' AS smalldatetime) 
 ) ; 
 INSERT INTO mytable DEFAULT VALUES; 

SET @Actualdatestring = (SELECT column_default 
                   FROM information_schema.columns 
                   WHERE table_name = 'mytable') ; 
--embed any string variables that need to be concatenated before calling sp_executesql
SET @dynsql  = 'Set @param =  (select ' + @Actualdatestring + ')'; 
set @paramdef = N'@param smalldatetime output'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @dynsql, @paramdef, @param = @Actualdefaultdate output;

if(@Actualdefaultdate <> @Requireddefaultdate)
begin
  print 'Error';
end
else
begin
  print 'OK'
end

--finally drop the table 
DROP TABLE dbo.mytable;
```